# auto reference to address in C++

Tags: c++11

I'm studying some C++ features, trying to play around with some experiments. However, I stuck in a place where it compiled error:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "some string";
    auto &c = str.begin(); // compile error
    *c = toupper(*c);
    cout << *c << ", str: " << str << endl;
}
```

I'm not sure why it was not acceptable. My thought was that `c` had type `char *` (a pointer to a `char`), so that's why I had written as above. But why it failed in compiling?

> Error C2440   Cannot transform 'std::_String_iteratorstd::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>' to'std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem

PS: Another method which I had tried first was OK.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "some string";
    auto &c = *str.begin(); // success
    c = toupper(c);
    cout << c << ", str: " << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: In questions about compiler errors, do include the actual error message! StackOverflow can often find an answer for you even while you are still writing your question. But you need to help out a bit.

Comment: Why do you need `c` to be a reference?

Comment: @JimRhodes No special intention, just for practicing and confirming my understanding of those mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`begin()` returns an iterator *by value*, not a reference. You are not allowed to form a non-`const` lvalue reference.

Making it `const` would prolong the life of the returned iterator and the program would then compile:

```
const auto &c = str.begin();
```

On the other hand, iterators are supposed to be cheap to copy and iterators from contiguous containers are often implemented as pure pointers. The idiomatic approach is:

```
auto c = str.begin();
```

---

In your second example, the idiomatic approach to form a reference to the first element would be:

```
auto& c = str.front();
```

Comment: I think I get it. So in my first example, writing `auto& c = str.begin()` is similar to writing something like `auto &c = 0x....` or `auto &c = 123`, which does not make sense right? Also, thank you for the compliment of the idiomatic way, which is quite useful to me!

Comment: @Eric You're welcome. Yes, I think you could make that comparison. It'd be ok to do `const auto& c = 123;` though :-)